# javascript code makes a page to be refreshed in aspx

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a button in aspx as you can see here:

```
        <input type="submit" name="AddMore3" value="+" id="BtnAddMore3" class="buttonSave" />
```

This button calls a javascript code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('input[name=AddMore3]').click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "-") {
            $('#DivMoreAuthor3').hide();
            var elem = document.getElementById("BtnAddMore3");
            elem.value = "+";
        } else {
            $('#DivMoreAuthor3').show();
            var elem1 = document.getElementById("BtnAddMore3");
            elem1.value = "-";
        }
    });
}
```

I put the buton in contentplaceholder and the javascript code in a javascript file .my problem is when the users click on the button the page is refreshed why ?

I can show more code for details if you need

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use suggested answers or just change type `submit` to `button` like following.

`<input type="button" name="AddMore3" value="+" id="BtnAddMore3" class="buttonSave" />`

And you don't have to change `javascript` for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `BtnAddMore3` is a submit button, so by default it submits the form when clicked. Try to change the click event handler to this

```
$('input[name=AddMore3]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).val() == "-") {
        $('#DivMoreAuthor3').hide();
        var elem = document.getElementById("BtnAddMore3");
        elem.value = "+";
    } else {
        $('#DivMoreAuthor3').show();
        var elem1 = document.getElementById("BtnAddMore3");
        elem1.value = "-";
    }
});
```

Comment: So in you code i just see an argument 'e' am i right ?you mean i should ad this e to all my function

Comment: Yes you're right, or you can also change the `type` attribute of `BtnAddMore3` to `button` if you don't want to change the function.